# Ruby on Rails match routing error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I'm trying to make a Rails application that serves simple static HTML pages. I followed Mikel's tutorial [here](http://lindsaar.net/2011/4/18/rails-static-pages) (it involves making a Pages controller and setting up some routing) but I keep getting an error message.

I made a `app/views/site/pages/_about.html.erb` file to contain my About page. After starting the `rails server`, I try to go to `http://localhost:3000/about/` but it gives me a Routing Error because I have an "uninitialized constant Site."

[My project is uploaded to GitHub](https://github.com/mytechnix/NINAgallery-on-Rails) if you want to take a look at the code.

Edit: here's my `config/routes.rb` file:

```
NINAgallery::Application.routes.draw do
  match ':page_name' => 'site/pages#show'
end
```

And here's the important part of my `app/controllers/pages_controller.rb` file:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController

  layout 'site'

  def show
    @page_name = params[:page_name].to_s.gsub(/\W/,'')
    unless partial_exists?(@page_name)
      render 'missing', :status => 404
    end
  end

  # extra code for handling 404 errors goes here

end
```

Comment: It's fixed! The GitHub link has the working code now.

Answer (score 1):

`site/pages#show` means the show action in `Site::PagesController`

You either need to put your controller in the namespace your routes imply or change the route

Answer (score 1):

The last line in the PagesController is this:

```
ValidPartials = Site::PagesController.find_partials
```

That means that the PagesController is contained in a Site module. But there is no Site module in your app.

I think simple removing Site:: should fix the problem:

```
ValidPartials = PagesController.find_partials
```

Plus the route:

```
match ':page_name' => 'pages#show'
```

Answer (score 1):

Your application is called `NINAgallery`.

Replace `Site` in `pages_controller.rb` line 27 by `NINAgallery`.

PS:

I just took a peek at the so-called tutorial. You are taking really really really bad habits.

Some resources to take very good basics:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/
- http://api.rubyonrails.org/

If you like tutorials: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

And there are plenty of books about rails. All good.

Comment: Why are these bad habits? I guess I don't yet understand the beauty of Ruby on Rails. :D

Comment: I'm sorry if I've been rude but thing is: bad habits are really difficult to lose and you may regret it later. With the links listed above, you're safe ;)

Comment: Oh, not at all! I just started developing in Rails, so I still don't know best habits yet. But the links above have pointed me in the direction of them! :)

Answer (score 0):

Besides the namespace problem, you also needed to add the 'app' Gem to the Gemfile, as explained in the tutorial.

I don't know why you removed the caching of the static pages in your working code. I made a pull request with the app working and maintaining the cache problem. If another person is interested, the code is [here](https://github.com/e3matheus/NINAgallery-on-Rails)

Also ryan bates has a tutorial called ["Semi static pages"](http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages) that does something similar. I would encourage you to follow his solutions because there are very rarely mistaken.